# Is it possible to ignore model for partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an ASP.NET MVC view with a model binding of a List

Inside my view I have a partial view that should handle a result of a different action and should be updated after the Action finished.

But the partial view is always crash because it tries to consume the model of the main view.

```
@model List<planemOsIdConsumer.Models.CommonDtosRole>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rollen und Rechte";
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Your Column Header Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>@Html.Display(item.Name)</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Role", new AjaxOptions
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, //target element(#mydiv) will be replaced
                UpdateTargetId = "mydiv"
            }))
            {
                <table cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rollenname:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Name" id="roleNameVal" placeholder="Neue Rolle" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />

                <label id="resultLabel"></label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_click" />

                <div id="mydiv">
                    @{
                        Html.RenderPartial("_CreateResult");
                    }
                </div>
            }
```

The Partial View

```
@model planemosIdUi.Dto.Result

@{
      ViewBag.Title = "_CreateResult";
}
@{
    if (Model?.Success == true)
    {
        <label>Erstellt</label>
    }
    else if(Model?.Success == false)
    {
        <label>Fehler</label>
    }
    else
    { 
        <label>Do something</label>
    }
}
```

The Partial view should ignore the model from the main view if this is possible.

Comment: what is your mean _the partial view is always crash_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You want to remove the Model class, thats mentioned at the top. Then only it won't ask for the model and Don't throw an error.
2. But based on your code, it should be there.
3. Pass the nullable model in your main CSHTML page as like below

```cs
Html.RenderPartial("_CreateResult", new planemosIdUi.Dto.Result());
```

Comment: This is the same solution i found for myself :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display the partial view after some action, you can use `ajax` for appending the partial view content to `mydiv` id .otherwise every time when you load the page, partial view will render.

```
 $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
      success: function (result) {
         $("#mydiv").html(result);
      }
 });
```

From the controller you can return the partial view as

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    planemosIdUi.Dto.Result model=new planemosIdUi.Dto.Result();// model object to partial view
    return PartialView("_CreateResult",model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your _CreateResult.cshtml requires model of type Result.cs, and you must pass the model inside Html.RenderPartial method which is the second parameter of it.

If you don't want to pass the model to partial view, you could do two things

1. Pass the null value and have check for null value inside partial view
   **Html.RenderPartial("_CreateResult", null);**
2. You could create the empty instance of model and pass it to partial view
   **Html.RenderPartial("_CreateResult", new planemOsIdConsumer.Models.CommonDtosRole());**